# Django URL - default value if the value doesn't exist

Tags: python, django

I am trying to set up a default value in case of no entry.

URL file:

```
url(r'^testApp/(?:(?P<view_id>test1|test2\w+)/)?$', testApp_views.main),
```

view file:

```
def main( request, view_id = 'test1'):
    print view_id
```

and in the console i see " None "

Do you know why ? 
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Make url like this

```
url(r'^testApp/$', testApp_views.main),
```

blank value gives error in url then you can pass value by GET parameters like "testapp/?view_id=test1"

And write your view as

```
def main(request):
    print request.GET.get("view_id", "test1")
```